# Device file vanishes after a reboot

Tags: boot, usb, usb-modem, devices

When I connected a USB modem to my machine, it complained that `/dev/sr1` does not exist. So, after a bit of Googling, I used the following commands to create this device.

```
ls -l /dev/sr*
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Aug 16 08:05 /dev/sr0

sudo mknod /dev/sr1 b 11 0
sudo chown -v :cdrom /dev/sr1
sudo chmod -v g+w /dev/sr1
ls -l /dev/sr*
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Aug 16 08:05 /dev/sr0
brw-rw-r--+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Aug 16 08:10 /dev/sr1
```

Then my modem worked without any problem. However, after a reboot, I find that the device has vanished, and I have to create the device again.

Please tell me,

- Why such a strange thing like a device vanishing is happening?
- How do I get rid of the situation?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

(As I am going to hit the Post button, I notice that creation date-time of `/dev/sr0` coincides with the boot time this morning.

Are the devices being created at boot time?

Looks like the answer is, yes, indeed,

```
ls -l /dev/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           7 Aug 16 08:14 atttyUSB1 -> ttyUSB1
crw-------  1 root root     10, 235 Aug 16 08:05 autofs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root         640 Aug 16 08:14 block
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root         120 Aug 16 08:14 bsg
crw-------  1 root root     10, 234 Aug 16 08:05 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root          60 Aug 16  2015 bus
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           3 Aug 16 08:14 cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           3 Aug 16 08:14 cdrw -> sr0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        4300 Aug 16 08:14 char
crw-------  1 root root      5,   1 Aug 16 08:06 console
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          11 Aug 16  2015 core -> /proc/kc

<snipped>
```

So, if I ask, which list do I update to cause  `/dev/sr1` created at boot time?, can we move in the right direction?
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the devices being created at boot time?

Yes.

> So, if I ask, which list do I update to cause /dev/sr1 created at boot time?

[makedev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/MAKEDEV.8.html)

```
DESCRIPTION

   MAKEDEV is a script that will  create  the  devices  in  /dev  used  to
   interface with drivers in the kernel.

   Note  that  programs  giving  the  error  ``ENOENT:  No  such  file  or
   directory'' normally means that the device  file  is  missing,  whereas
   ``ENODEV:  No such device'' normally means the kernel does not have the
   driver configured or loaded.
```

Regarding your `sr1`:

```
CDROM DEVICES

   sr or scd or scd-all
          Creates scd{0..16} SCSI CD players and  sr{0..16}  symlinks  for
          these  devices.   cdrom is a symlink which can be created by the
          user to the active CD device.  It is not created by MAKEDEV.
```